# Reassemble RAID10 after install

Tags: ubuntu, raid-10

My system drive broke so I have lost the software RAID10 I had.
Is there any way to reassemble the RAID10 when I have installed a new system?

I ran Ubuntu server 17.10.1, aiming to do the same again.

Comment: This is doable. What have you googled, where are you stuck? (If you haven't, try googling "mdadm rebuild raid10")

Comment: I have googled but haven't found what I want, with your example I got more what I wanted so thanks!